# How to best to select items from other tables when grouping by primary keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have had the following occur a few times and my solution feels crude.

Generically I have a tables that might look like this:

```
WorkOrder:
    WorkOrderID (primary key)
    WorkOrderDesc

Process:
   ProcessID (primary key)
   ProcessDesc

Work:
   ProcessID
   WorkOrderID
```

I want to find out how many processes that have been done on a work order so I do something like

```
select w.WorkOrderId,w.ProcessID,Count(*)
from Work as w
    inner join WorkOrder as wo on w.WorkOrderID=wo.WorkOrderID
    inner join Process as p on w.ProcessID = p.ProcessID
group by w.WorkOrderID,w.ProcessID
```

This code will tell me how many times each process was run on each work order.

The problem I run into is that I really don't want the query results to be the indexes, I want it to be the descriptions because those will be reported on or plotted. Because it is a **group by** I know that **WorkOrderID** and **ProcessID** are unique I know that all descriptions will be the same so I can just take the Max of those entries (or the Min).

```
select w.WorkOrderId,w.ProcessID,Count(*),Max(w.WorkOrderDesc),Max(p.ProcessDesc)
from Work as w
    inner join WorkOrder as wo on w.WorkOrderID=wo.WorkOrderID
    inner join Process as p on w.ProcessID = p.ProcessID
group by w.WorkOrderID,w.ProcessID
```

This query gives me the ID's like the first query but it also fills in the descriptions.

Is there a way to make this type of query as a single query without using this hack?  I know I could use a CTE where the results of first query are joined a second time to grab the descriptions from the two tables but that seems like it ends up running the same(ish) query again.

It seems like the query engine could detect that I am grouping by a primary key and allow me select items from that row in the select statement.

Note: I realize I could have done the queries by just using the descriptions in this toy example, in a real example each of these queries would have many items reported in the query that all come from the joined tables.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a hack; what you've written is just an aggregated query. But (if I understand what you're trying to say correctly) no, T-SQL doesn't support implied `GROUP BY` statements. You must be explicit on what values you are aggregating on, and what values you are aggregating.

Comment: If I know they will all be the same because they all come from from a table that I'm grouping by using the primary key, then the SQL engine should see that too.  It seems provable that when grouping by a primary key, that every value from the row in the primary key's table could be safely selected without adorning it with a Max() or Min() or running a second query.

Comment: If they are all the same, then include the columns in the `GROUP BY`. T-SQL is designed to not allow implied `GROUP BY` statements, they have to be explicit. If you omit a column from the `GROUP BY` and don't surround it with an aggregate function then you will receive an error. They is the way that T-SQL is designed. If you're not happy with that functionality you'll have to use a different RDBMS which does allow such syntax; such as MySQL. It's unlikely that the behaviour you're talking about is going to change (soon); it's certainly not in SQL Server 2019 Preview.

Comment: Why not add w.WorkOrderDesc to the group by and remove it from an aggregate? Would it not give the same results? It should, if it's truly unique too

Comment: @Larnu, this isn't really a in "implied group by".  If I've grouped by a unique key, then the elements of the row defined by that key are unique and *could* be safely added to the select statement with no ambiguity.  It appears that this is not a feature of tsql.  (you should write a you can't do that with tsql answer to this question)

Comment: @scsimon because my example only shows two columns, one for each table being joined, in the real problem there are many columns from each table in my select, each adorned with Max().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT wo.WorkOrderDesc, p.ProcessDesc, x.Cnt
FROM (
    SELECT w.WorkOrderId,w.ProcessID,Count(*) AS Cnt
    from Work as w
    group by w.WorkOrderID,w.ProcessID
) x
inner join WorkOrder as wo on x.WorkOrderID=wo.WorkOrderID
inner join Process as p on x.ProcessID = p.ProcessID
```

This way, the grouping is done using the ID, but we later retrieve the description for each ID which appears in the results.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to do it.